# Pass values to default NewForm.aspx

Tags: list-view, calendar, modal-dialog, aspx

I need to pass values from my list-view (calendar) to the default newform.aspx. As you propably know, you can click the "add" button on a day within the calendar view. Then the day get's automaticly selected. What I want is a bit the same. I want to get the name of the view (there are about 20...), pass this to the newform.aspx and select a value from a combobox. Anyone who knows how to do this?

I don't want to modify each view to add some js/jquery code. So if possible only modify the newform.aspx-page.

Comment: You could add JS globally (_AdditionalPageHEad_, _ScriptLink_, edit MasterPage etc) though, and make a conditional for URL or some information from DOM. Would this suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by storing values within my cookie:

**General script (added on masterpage):**

```
function GetMeetingRoomPage()
{
    if (document.URL.indexOf('/sites/meetingrooms/Lists/Reservations/') >= 0)//Check if correct URL
    {
        var meetingRoomViewControl = "<id or class view>";
        if (jQuery(meetingRoomViewControl).length)//Check if control exists
        {

            setCookie("meetingRoomView", jQuery(meetingRoomViewControl).html(), "1");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setCookie("meetingRoomView", "", "1");
    }
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++)
    {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

**Script within my newpage.aspx**

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(procAuditArgs, "sp.js");

function procAuditArgs(){
    var meetingRoomView = getCookie("meetingRoomView");
    if(meetingRoomView != "")
    {
        var meetingRoomControl = "<id or class combobox>";
        jQuery(meetingRoomControl + " option").each(function()
        {
            if(jQuery(this).text().indexOf(meetingRoomView) >= 0)
            {
                jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
            }
        });
    }
}
```